# Gulp Browserify with glob and uglify/factor-bundle

Tags: gulp, browserify

I'm currently getting into browserify. I like it so far but before I start using it I want to automate it. Gulp is the build system of my choice.

So what I actually want to do is:

Get `js/app/**.js`, bundle it to `js/bundle/` and extract common dependencies into `js/bundle/common.js`. In addition uglify everything and add source maps.

Well. The gulp support for browserify kinda seems poor, at least my google researches were pretty disappointing.

Anyway. What I've got so far.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    factor = require('factor-bundle');

// ...

// gulp task
return browserify({
    entries: ['js/app/page1.js', 'js/app/page2.js'],
    debug: true
})
    .plugin(factor, {
        o: ['js/bundle/page1.js', 'js/bundle/page2.js']
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('common.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/bundle/'));
```

Well this is neither uglifying nor adding sourcemaps and much less using a glob pattern. I can find an [official recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md) which shows me how to use the pipe to add additional transformations like uglify. But it's only for a single file.

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I'd be interested in a solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

as an outputs parameter to factor-bundle, use streams instead of file paths. You can do whatever you want with the streams then.

```
  var indexStream = source("index.js");
  var testStream = source("tests.js");
  var commonStream = bundler.plugin('factor-bundle', { outputs: [indexStream, testStream] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('common.js'));


  return merge(indexStream, commonStream, testStream)
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ debug: true, loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/bundle/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Liero's answer, I got something very similar working.  Here's the complete gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const factor = require('factor-bundle');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const buffer = require('gulp-buffer');
const merge = require('gulp-merge');

gulp.task('bfb', function () {

    const fejs = 'public/javascripts/'  // location of source JS
    const fejsb = fejs + 'b/';          // location of bundles
    const modules = [ // aka entry points
        'accounts',
        'invoice',
        'invoices',
        // etc...
    ];
    const inputs = [];
    const streams = [];

    modules.forEach(function (module) {
        inputs.push(fejs + module + '.js');
        streams.push(source(module + '.js'));
    });

    const bundler = browserify(inputs, {});
    const commonStream = bundler.plugin(factor, { outputs: streams })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('common.js'));
    streams.push(commonStream);

    return merge(streams)
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        //.pipe(uglify())  // haven't tested this bit
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fejsb));

});
```